# How to cut/paste method signature without type in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any extension that when copying this

```
aMethod(string mystring,ref long mylong, int myint = 100) 
or just
(string mystring,ref long mylong, int myint = 100)
```

will paste

```
(mystring,mylong,myint)
```

Sometimes I want to break apart "aMethod" in two (or more) methods. aMethod will still be the frontend but will cascade some computations to another(s) method(s) that will take (more or less) the same arguments.

```
mymethod(string mystring,ref long mylong,int myint = 100){..}
```

will become

```
mymethod(string mystring,ref long mylong, int myint = 100){
...
var x = mynewmethod(mystring,mylong,myint);
// or maybe x = mynewmethod(mystring,mylong,myint,anotherarg);
... 
}
```

Of course I could just cut/paste then clean up (all the "string", "int", "ref" and so on) but this becomes tedious when there are tenths of arguments.

Comment: Search and replace?

Comment: You are asking how to refactor method signature to have 7.0 tuples instead of multiple parameters. You could use a normal method signature refactoring for this. I don't use Resharper myself, but [it should be able to do it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html).

Comment: @HimBromBeere. The regexp would probably a bit too much complicated for me

Comment: @Sinatr. Hum no this is not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command (Language C#) for my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (ts == null)
            return;
        EnvDTE.CodeFunction func = ts.ActivePoint.CodeElement[EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction] as EnvDTE.CodeFunction;
        if (func == null)
            return;

        string result = "";
        foreach(EnvDTE.CodeParameter i in func.Parameters)
        {
            if (result.Length > 0)
                result += ", ";
            result += i.Name;
        }
        ts.Text = "(" + result + ")";
    }
}
```

When you call this command with the caret inside the aMethod body, it will insert comma separated function parameter names.